# About Ruby Flow Control in If/Elsif function?

Tags: ruby

Please bear with me as I am very new to learning Ruby. Not entirely sure how to word my question but its about the order in which I had written this code.

```
output = Hash.new
input.each do |word|
    dictionary.each do |reference|
        if (word.include? reference) && output[reference] = nil
            output[reference] = 1
        elsif word.include? reference
            output[reference] += 1
        end
    end     
end
```

The above code returns an error while the one below works the way I would like it to. Basically, my question is why does one work and not the other? Logically, I'm interpreting them as pretty much the same.

```
output = Hash.new
input.each do |word|
    dictionary.each do |reference|
        if (word.include? reference) && output[reference] != nil
            output[reference] += 1
        elsif word.include? reference
            output[reference] = 1
        end
    end     
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you wrote an assignment:

```
output[reference] = nil
```

where you wanted to have a [comparison](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AssignmentVsEqualityOperator)?

```
output[reference] == nil
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, that was exactly it. Thank you so much!